Переслать сообщение в telegram bot aiogram python,после нажатия Инлайн-кнопки
есть код
@router.callback_query(F.data == "тз")
async def tpl(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer(text="скидывай")
    while True:
        if router.message == '  ':
            print("Пасхалко")
        else:
            @router.message()
            async def qq(message: types.Message):
                chat_id = message.chat.id
                await bot.send_message(text="ваш заказ отправлен,скоро он будет готов\nперебрасываю вас в меню)", reply_markup=kb.menu,chat_id=message.from_user.id)
                await message.forward(chat_id=5987603537)

            break

мне нужно чтобы после того как пользователь нажмет на кнопку и отправит сообщение,оно перешлется мне,а у пользователя откроется меню.Но проблема в том,что у меня все работает,но после отправки мне,каждое сообщение от пользователя отправляется мне,хотя нужно чтобы она отправлялось мне только после нажатия кнопки.Помогите пожалуйста кто может
